# Why is Analytics Reporting Api data not matching with Google Analytics Dashboard?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am working on an analytics module which pulls data from Google Analytics, Facebook and Twitter Analytics api.

Using Analytics Reporting Api V4 to pull the data from Google Analytics.
`Total number of sessions` value does not match with what I see on Dashboard. I am using metric `ga:sessions` to pull the number of sessions.

In some cases, the number of sessions coming from reporting api matches with Dashboard. But not all the time. I am finding it hard to get it approved from QA without a proper explanation.

I checked dimension filters and reporting query multiple times but couldn't find anything wrong with it.

Added the `samplingLevel` to my report request but still seeing the same result.

```
ReportRequest totalNumberOfSessions = new ReportRequest().setViewId(VIEW_ID)
                .setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(lifetime))
                .setDimensions(Arrays.asList(custom))
                .setDimensionFilterClauses(Arrays.asList(clause))
                .setMetrics(Arrays.asList(sessions))
                .setSamplingLevel("LARGE");
```

Comment: The most common reason is the data is sampled, can you confirm whether or not your query contains sampled data?

Comment: @PhilipWalton What do you mean by sampled data? If you want I can update the question with the code.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics#sampling

Comment: I think Sampling size should not be a problem. The discrepancy is with the number of total session for a custom variable. For example, Dashboard is showing 35 sessions but api is returning 31 sessions for the same custom variable. It is happening for almost half of the custom variables.

Comment: Sampling is the only common reason. If your results aren't sampled, then it's impossible to know what the reason is without knowing the details of the API request vs. the UI report. FWIW, 99% of the time people report this (for non-sampled reports), the cause is subtle differences between the API request and the report.

Comment: @PhilipWalton Updated the report request with `samplingLevel` but still seeing the same result.

Comment: You said your reports weren't sampled, which means the `samplingLevel` option will have no effect. Also, you still haven't given any specific details about your API request and the GA dashboard report you're comparing it to. Without details, there's nothing anyone can do to help.

Comment: Does your result have values for the fields [`ReportData.FIELDS.samplesReadCounts`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportData.samples_read_counts) or [`ReportData.samplingSpaceSizes `](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportData.FIELDS.sampling_space_sizes)?

Comment: @Matt No. `report.getData().getSamplesReadCounts()` and `report.getData().getSamplingSpaceSizes()` both are coming back as null.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples, use setSegments instead of setDimensionFilterClauses.
Like this:

```
    String path = "<your_path>";
    SegmentDimensionFilter exactPathDimensionFilter = new SegmentDimensionFilter()
            .setDimensionName("ga:pagePath").setOperator("EXACT")
            .setExpressions(Arrays.asList(path));
    SegmentFilterClause exactPathSegmentFilterClause = new SegmentFilterClause()
            .setDimensionFilter(exactPathDimensionFilter);
    OrFiltersForSegment orFiltersForSegment = new OrFiltersForSegment()
            .setSegmentFilterClauses(Arrays.asList(exactPathSegmentFilterClause));
    SimpleSegment simpleSegment = new SimpleSegment()
            .setOrFiltersForSegment(Arrays.asList(orFiltersForSegment));
    SegmentFilter segmentFilter = new SegmentFilter()
            .setSimpleSegment(simpleSegment);
    SegmentDefinition segmentDefinition = new SegmentDefinition()
            .setSegmentFilters(Arrays.asList(segmentFilter));
    DynamicSegment dynamicSegment = new DynamicSegment().setSessionSegment(
            segmentDefinition).setName("Path pageviews");
    Segment segment = new Segment().setDynamicSegment(dynamicSegment);

    ReportRequest request = new ReportRequest().setViewId(VIEW_ID)
            .setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(dateRange))
            .setMetrics(Arrays.asList(metric))
            .setDimensions(Arrays.asList(new Dimension().setName("ga:segment")))
            .setSegments(Arrays.asList(segment));
```

This example uses a path filter. You should change it according to your "clause" variable.